# Java API design: capturing lambdas versus additional parameters

Tags: java, lambda, api-design

In C#, a common optimization for methods that use delegates is to provide an overloaded method with an additional argument that lets you eliminate free variables from the lambda.

For example:

```
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>
{
    public TValue GetOrAdd (TKey key, Func<TKey,TValue> valueFactory);
    public TValue GetOrAdd<TArg> (TKey key, Func<TKey,TArg,TValue> valueFactory, TArg factoryArgument);
}
```

The "factoryArgument" in the second overload lets you use a static delegate for valueFactory instead of a closure, eliminating the need to allocate a new object each time the method is called with new arguments.

Java also has lambda expressions. However, the method for translating them into MethodHandles is different than C#. From what I've read, since the transformation is deferred until execution, Java can transparently eliminate free variables for capturing lambdas. Thus, whether or not calling a lambda expression allocates a new object is runtime-dependent.

If I'm designing a Java API that uses lambdas, would it still be worthwhile to provide overloaded methods similar to C#?

e.g.

```
interface Foo<T>
{
    public T get(Supplier<? extends T> supp);
    public <A> T get(Function<? super A, ? extends T> supp, A arg);
}
```

Or is it best to rely on the runtime to provide any optimizations and only include a single method?

e.g.

```
interface Foo<T>
{
    public T get(Supplier<? extends T> supp);
}
```

**To clarify** my main question is: considering the differences in how the Java and C# runtimes translate closures, is providing an overload with manual lambda-lifting necessary in Java?

Comment: Would it be worthwhile to design a Java API based on lessons learned as a C# developer? No. Unless you're developing it especially for C# developers who don't like change.

Comment: No problem. So your question is whether it's better for a caller to do `get(someVar::method)` vs `get(SomeClass::method, someVar)`?

Comment: Not "whether it's better for a caller to do". Rather, due to the differences in how the C# and Java runtimes handle lambdas, whether it's even necessary to provide the overload.

Comment: It's definitely not necessary in Java. There's no such boiler-plate idiom in Java lambdas.